# How to apply AutomaticGainControl and AcousticEchoCanceler with AudioManager

Tags: android, voip, plivo

I have used this code in the past:

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(getContext().AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.setParameters("noise_suppression=off");
```

Which is roughly equivalent to:

```
NoiseSuppressor ns;
ns = NoiseSuppressor.create(sessionID);
```

But it applies the effect to all sessions. Is there any way to do the same with `AcousticEchoCanceler` and `AutomaticGainControl` effects?

The problem is that the audio session I'm trying to adjust the gain to, is created by some external process and I cannot determine the `sessionID`, so it would be enough for me to apply the effect to all sessions if only it could be done in a way similar to `am.setParameters("noise_suppression=off");`

FYI, the audio is being recorded by a VoIP framework embedded in my app (Plivo) but there is no way to access the stream to apply the effects.

Comment: I have the same requirement, do you have any update on this question?

Comment: Hi any update on turning off AGC?